# logrotate error "error: error opening /home/web/logs/dev.log.10: No such file or directory"

Tags: logrotate

In a run, sometimes I get such type of errors for any of the log file.
Below is my configuration:

```
/home/web/logs/*.log.* {            
missingok     
copytruncate
olddir rotate
rotate 5000
compress
maxage 1
delaycompress
notifempty
    }
```

1) I want to know when does this happens?
2) Is there any impact on my log rotation?
3) How can I avoid it?